# Can Vue component have both data and props?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Standard example of component in Vue looks like that:

```
Vue.component('blog-post', {
  // camelCase in JavaScript
  props: ['postTitle'],
  template: '<h3>{{ postTitle }}</h3>'
})
```

In basic docs about components there's no data object used, just props. However [documentation of data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data) mentions components:

> Restriction: Only accepts Function when used in a component
> definition.

There's even example:

```
var data = { a: 1 }

// direct instance creation
var vm = new Vue({
  data: data
})
vm.a // => 1
vm.$data === data // => true

// must use function when in Vue.extend()
var Component = Vue.extend({
  data: function () {
    return { a: 1 }
  }
})
```

Does it mean that component can have both data and props? Is data kind of private property (if we'd like to compare to OOP) and property public one?

Comment: They can have both, `props` are received by the parent component while `data` are manipulated by the component. The `props` are static (changeable by the parent) while `data` are dynamic (but cannot be changed by the parent).

Comment: Great. Could you please make it an answer :)?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I always change props value in component ! Is this good practice ?

Comment: @DavidJorHpan it is not a good practice and Vue shouldn't allow you to do so. Don't you see an error message in the console (like this exemple: https://jsfiddle.net/6yyqzog8/)

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I do only on prop type `array or object` , they don't show that console error ! For string type of prop , I use `$emit` !!

Comment: @DavidJorHpan Indeed, it doesn't show the error since they are not surcharging methods like `.push` or the `get` handler in your object. Still, it is not a good practice. If you want to use the prop as default data value, you can have a self-calling function in the data, ie: https://jsfiddle.net/6yyqzog8/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Components can have both `props` and `data`. The difference between them is that `props` are received by the parent component while `data` are manipulated by the component. The props are static (changeable by the parent) while data are dynamic (but cannot be changed by the parent).

The only way a child component can affect a property is by emitting events. The parent component can listen to those events and receive and receive anything in the payload argument. In the listener function, they can change their own data and the child property will be updated as well. This is known as the one-way data flow:

> All props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child, but not the other way around. This prevents child components from accidentally mutating the parent’s state, which can make your app’s data flow harder to understand.
>
> [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)

Here's a little schema if you're visual:

[image]